# Rails 3.2 access public image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm on Rails 3.2, and my image `im.png` is located in `app/assets/images`. How can I access it on my website? I've tried `app/assets/images/im.png` and `im.png`, but neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `image_tag` helper:

`<%= image_tag('im.png') %>`

Which will generate a URL like:

`/assets/im.png`

Which is a "virtual" URL and doesn't exist on disk - but the asset pipeline will serve it from `app/assets/images/im.png` where it does in fact reside on disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= image_tag("im.png") %>
```

Returns an HTML tag for the image:

```
<img src="/assets/im.png" />
```

You can use either and you will get the same result.